# Influence matrix in Cross validation

Tags: regression, smoothing, splines

I am trying to implement  cross validation to find the apropriate smoothing parameter value for smoothing spline
I am able to implement the leave out one , in which one data point is left out , then it is prdicted and RMS is calculated.

the other method is working with an influence martix.
Whose S(i,i) elements are considered, according to the formula.
I am not able to understand , what defines the nxn influence matrix.
Is it the predicted values influence matrix , or data on x or y axis , or somthingelse.
[image]

I would like to know what is S matrix , and how is it derived.
image  is from [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947302001597)

Comment: I have  asked this question at many places , but no body is able to answer this. Kindly let me know the answer of this question!!!